# What word can I use to mean "something which is scavenged?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for something similar in connotation to "curio," "knickknack," or "bauble," but which carries a strong implication that the item was found by happenstance (particularly while looking for something not directly related). I imagine I might remark that an object I keep in my room is "just a _____ I fished out of a flea market" if a friend asks about its origin. Is there a noun so specific?

Comment: Salvage. But it’s a mass noun, not a count noun.

Answer (score 2):

The Macmillan dictionary defins the noun (as oposed to the verb) [find](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/find_2) as

> something good, interesting, or valuable that you discover by chance

with examples

> The statue could be one of the finds of the century.

And

> Our new nanny is a real find

This is probably the most common and most widely understood word for something acquired serendipitously.

Answer (score 0):

As in:

> I might remark that an object I keep in my room is "just a **tot** I
>   fished out of a flea market" if a friend asks about its origin.

**tot**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/203786#eid18072166) a noun

slang.

> A dust-heap picker's name for a bone; whence by extension,
>   **anything worth picking from a refuse-heap or elsewhere.**

From **[World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-tot1.htm)**:

Totters [collectors of **tots**] were familiar sight in the streets of every town and city in old Britain, often announcing their presence with the ringing of a handbell and the cry of “rags, bones, bottles”.

A more contemporary word would be:

> I might remark that an object I keep in my room is "just **crap** I
>   fished out of a flea market" if a friend asks about its origin.

**crap**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/43863#eid1210633080)

> - a. originally U.S. Unspecified objects, materials, events,    activities, etc., of any sort; stuff, things; (sometimes) spec. (with 
>     possessive adjective) personal belongings.
> - b. Rubbish, trash; anything regarded as worthless or inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Magpie's treasure
Implying a glittering treasure, enough to attract a magpie.
'just a magpie's treasure I found at the flea market'.

Treasure
Something found, hoarded or stolen, as by pirates.
'just a treasure I found at the flea market'.

Note that the more you 'up' the value of the treasure, the more contrast you get with 'just' and 'flea market'.

Example: 'just a Tzarina's treasure I found at the flea market'.

It could be a mermaid's treasure, or a pirate's treasure, and so on.

A pleasure, a trinket

Pleasure is another option 'a mermaid's pleasure'. If it's a valuable item, and you describe it as a 'trinket' you can go the other way with the contrast. 'Just a queen's trinket I found at the flea market.'

Trawl?

It would be poetic, because trawl really refers to the net, although, a fisherman's trawl is his fish, I think.  but maybe the idea that 'I fished with my net and randomly found this' would help?

'just a trawl I found at the flea market'.

Haul
Similarly 'haul' which implies the treasure gained by a thief, might have the right feeling of 'bit picking'.
'part of a haul I scored at the flea market'

Magpie's haul, magpie's treasure
Implying that you're a magpie, as those birds are known for picking 'those glittery attractive bits'.

'just a magpie's haul I found at the flea market'

I hope these inspire you, I had fun pondering this, I love flea markets and treasure!

Answer (score 0):

These might be called ***found objects***

This art term is described [here](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/art-terms/f/found-object) as:

> A found object is a natural or man-made object, or fragment of an object, that is found (or sometimes bought) by an artist and kept because of some intrinsic interest the artist sees in it
>
> Found objects (sometimes referred to by the French term for found object ‘objet trouvé’) may be put on a shelf and treated as works of art in themselves, as well as providing inspiration for the artist